# How to get filter in serializers in REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two tables, they have same column "maid", and some of (instad of all) maid's unitcode is "U", they have units in table dep. I want to get units when the address's maid is exist in dep. The result I want is like below:

```
   [ {
        "addline": "14075 110A Ave",
        "city": "Surrey",
        "unitcode": "U",
        "maid": 113091
    },
    {
        "addline": "14143 110A Ave",
        "city": "Surrey",
        "unitcode": "S",
        "maid": 113104,
        "unit": [ "A-101", "A-102", "A-103", "A-104"]
    }
  ]
```

My views.py is as below:

```
def list(self, request, city):
    if city is not None:
        queryset = address.objects.filter(city__icontains=city)
    serializer = ResultSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My models is as below:

```
class address(models.Model):
    maid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    fulladdress = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    unitcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class dep(models.Model):
    maid = models.IntegerField()
    Unit = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

And my serializers.py is as below:

```
class DepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = dep
        fields = ('Unit', )

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    units = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_unit')
    def get_unit(self, queryset):
        queryset_unit = dep.objects.filter(maid=queryset.maid)
        serializer = DepSerializer(instance=queryset_unit, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = address
        fields = ('fulladdress', 'city', 'unitcode', 'units')
```

It seems OK, but server response is 500. I have been afflicted by this problem for almost whole day, anyone can save me?

Update:

After closing the debug button, I found the real problem:

```
LINE 1: ..."Unit" FROM "Company_dep" WHERE "Company_dep"."maid" = 73643
                                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

As I think, the problem is in this code:

```
queryset_unit = dep.objects.filter(maid=queryset.maid)
```

Because some of maid don't have a unit, how can pass when the maid is not exist in dep?

update2:

After open debug, finally I found the problem, the reason why is that in my PostgreSql, maid is varchar, and in models.py, I set it as IntegerField.

Just change this code:

```
maid = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Http 500` exception (Internal Server Error) raises because you may be defined 
`DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py`. You could see the original exception and traceback if you set it to `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` file
Your serializer seems fine, but `views` don't. So change your views as below

```
def list(self, request, city=None):
    queryset= address.objects.all()
    if city is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(city__icontains=city)
    serializer = ResultSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: open debug is a really helpful for me, I found the reason why bug happens. Could you please see the update in my question and give me more suggestions?

Comment: Finally, I found the problem, the reason why is that in my PostgreSql, maid is varchar, and in models.py, I set it as IntegerField. Really thanks! your answer really helps me.